# Domain name including city name or country name

Tags: domains

I am interested whether it is legally possible for a private person to register a domain name which includes city or country name extended by other phrases? Such as carservicecityname.com or countrynamecarservice.com?

Comment: Why wouldn't it be?

Comment: Why would you want to setup domain names like this. If you have many city names, then it is better to register one domain name for your service and the use either server redirects (ie. .htaccess) to subdomains or serve different car/city combinations via a database. It is far better to concentrate your SEO efforts on one domain and it become popular, and thereby increase the rankings for all of your car/city combinations than to duplicate this effort for many domains.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. That is a good solution you explained, however I would like to start a website focusing on only one location. Therefor I was not sure whether it is legally acceptable to use city or country name in the domain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to WSE. For .com/.net/.org there is no limitation on domain ownership except in the case of breach of trademark or copyright (ie. cocacola). And even with that, it would need to be a trademark on a word, words or phrase, not a logo, for you to be unable to register it without losing it.

City and country names and landmarks are not covered by trademark or copyright.

There are other regulatory limitations on other localised (such as .au ) or specialised domain names (such as .pro and .travel) however I know of no other domain names where the above isn't true for city and country names and geographical landmarks.

Answer (score 0):

According to copyright laws, you can't use a name for a business copyrighted for your business exactly like that. 
Example: BMW

But with within the cyber space, you don't need to worry much.

You have the right to choose the domain names. Even you can get a domain name bmwfanstokyo.com

But for good or bad, these companies might have purchased most of the good sounding and spelling domains that they would need in their near or far projects.

There might occur a problem only when you have content that they have issues with.

For example, Sony has the copyright to broadcast the IPL live and you are giving an online streaming in your website, they will surely send you a notice after which they will take it forward with the court if you are good enough to drag more or a good amount of traffic like them.